# Translate recorded message on iPhone

Tags: ios, internationalization

A person left message in foreign language (Mandarin) on my iPhone.
Please inform what should be done for translate it by voice and have text of this message.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. - If you need to clarify a question, there is an [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/459320/edit) command under each post. This works for open and [closed questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459323/).

Answer (score 0):

I would launch the Dictation feature available in both macOS and Windows, and play the recording on the phone.  Then send the text to DeepL.com (which is a better translator than Google).

I'm sure Linux has a dictation app available.

If you don't have a computer, you could borrow an iPhone or iPad and use Dictation on that.

Comment: Assuming the OP owns a Mac or a PC.

Comment: Point taken.  I'm sure Linux has a dictation app available.  But a linux user probably wouldn't need to ask.  I'll edit.